Midea Extreme Save Air-conditioner Leaking blue
Hello just had this ac unit installed 3 weeks ago. It was perfectly fine at first but today when I woke up I noticed the blue line in the middle of the ac. I was hoping someone knows more about it than me.
I still have the warranty so the installer should be coming to take a look at it as well.


